# How to disable time slots according to service time?

Tags: php, jquery, timepicker

Can anyone help me to solve the time slot query in which we can disable particular time slot in a day?(i.e: If the provided service[meeting room booking] is already booked then it should not be selectable)
like on this website: http://iconoffices.co.uk/bookingmeetingroom.php

Comment: What is "this website"? And if you already have some kind of "time slot query", where is it? Which technology do you use?

Comment: http://iconoffices.co.uk/bookingmeetingroom.php This is website link, if you select any date that is already booked then it will show disable time slot. and it's in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `disableTimeRanges` options as bellow:

```
$('#time1').timepicker({disableTimeRanges: [['3:00am', '4:30am'], ['5:00pm', '8:00pm']]});
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kiidkupy/8johph6L/4/